# Extracting text nested within several tags with Beautiful Soup — Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the text "12:25 AM - 30 Mar 2015" with Beautiful Soup from the  html below. This is how the html looks after being processed by BS:

```
<span class="u-floatLeft"> · </span>
<span class="u-floatLeft">
<a class="ProfileTweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" href="/TBantl/status/582333634931126272" title="5:08 PM - 29 Mar 2015">
<span class="js-short-timestamp " data-aria-label-part="last" data-long-form="true" data-time="1427674132">
Mar 29
  </span>
```

I have this code, but it doesn't work:

```
date = soup.find("a",attrs={"class":"ProfileTweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip"})["title"]
```

Comment: What is `chunk`? Also, are you sure the desired element is really present in the HTML you are parsing?

Comment: Please define "*it doesn't work*" - what output do you get? Are there any errors? If so, please [edit] your question and give the full text of them.

Comment: @MattDMo yeah, that's why I decided to ask, the code looks good. Most likely, the OP copied the HTML representation of an element from the browser without checking that the element is actually present in the HTML parsed by `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @alecxe `chunk` is my name for the `soup` in this case. I have edited the question to show the Beautiful Soup'ed html, where the element is present.

Comment: @textnet your code looks fine actually. Try playing around with different parsers. e.g. `chunk = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')` or `chunk = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')` or `chunk = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<span class="u-floatLeft">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="u-floatLeft">
          <a class="ProfileTweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" href="/indoz1/status/582443448927543296" title="12:25 AM - 30 Mar 2015">
          <span class="js-short-timestamp " data-aria-label-part="last" data-time="1427700314" data-long-form="true">
       """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
date = soup.find("a", attrs={"class": "ProfileTweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip"})["title"]

>>> print(date)
'12:25 AM - 30 Mar 2015'
```

Without more information, I suspect that you didn't transform your HTML snippet into a BeautifulSoup object. In that case, you'd get a `TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments`.

Or, as alexce [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375419/extracting-text-nested-within-several-tags-with-beautiful-soup-python/29375570#comment46931348_29375419) in the comments above, the item you are looking for may not actually be present in the HTML you are parsing. In that case, `date` would be empty.

---

Finally, completely unrelated to the issues you're having above - if you're then going to parse `date` into a `datetime` object, there's an easier way to do it. Just grab the `"data-time"` field from `<span class="js-short-timestamp " ... >` and parse it using [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

# get "data-time" field value as string named timestamp
data_time = dt.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp))

>>> print(data_time)
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 30, 3, 25, 14)
```

Comment: You really made everything you could possibly have taking into account the lack of information you had. Great effort! :)

Comment: @MattDMo ´date = chunk2.find("a",attrs={"class":"js-short-timestamp "})["data-time"]´ gives me ´TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'´

Comment: @textnet `chunk2.find()` should be looking for a `"span"` in this instance, not an `"a"`. Change that, and your code should work.